# PyQt design: A floating widget wrapped by another widget

Tags: layout, widget, pyqt

this is my first question here, I hope to be as clear as possible.

I have a Widget with two inner elements: WidgetA should be on the top-right and WidgetB should wrap the first around (so the text inside it should go below WidgetA).

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
________________________
|  _________     _____ |
|  |   B    |    | A | |
|  |  some  |    |___| |
|  |  text  |--------- |
|  | should go here  | |  
|  |_________________| |
|______________________|
```

- I have searched a whole day but couldn't find anything that can match with my case.
- I've tried to build a [FlowLayout](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/07c17233c1d3cb0f7a4b6e0bbfcc641ef4b4f5a4/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py) but still doesn't what I want.
- I've tried to design it putting HTML and CSS in a QLabel, but I've found that in PyQt there's no support for float (shame on you, Nokia!!)
- I've started to build custom QGraphicsView + QGraphicsItem, but it's a bit difficoult for me and I hope that maybe there's a simpler solution.

What layout are you guys suggest me to use?
Should I write my own custom layout?

In my particular case, WidgetA is a QLabel (with a QPixmap) and WidgetB is a QFormLayout (I now that this is not a Widget, but I've thought that maybe in this way is more helpful to other people).

I've built a code example, but this is more a design question and maybe the code doesn't matter so much.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        self.smallLabel = QtGui.QLabel("small small")

        self.longLabel = QtGui.QLabel('''
            very very very very very very very 
            very very very very very very very 
            very very very very very very very
            long label''')
        self.longLabel.setWordWrap(True)

        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.longLabel)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.smallLabel)


        self.layout.addLayout(self.hLayout)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

# I run this in Maya, so I don't care about  __main__ and apps      
w = MyWidget()
w.show()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a [QWebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html)? This is a Webkit-based browser widget, which you can also use for displaying static HTML. This should support most of CSS and HTML.

Comment: Looks like I don't have the QtWebKit built in my python, I have to compile it before trying. Thanks for the tip!